# How to make rigid body objects follow inside a moving container

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to create a falling bucket with dynamic (Rigid Body) objects falling out of it.

I've created a compound shape of my bucket, and applied a passive RB on it. It works perfectly when the objects fall into it, but as soon as it starts to move (the buckets), the object stay where they are, and thus, pass through the bucket.

Any clues why the Bucket Passive Rigid body does not work when moved?

thx.
Marc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found my answer!

1. Needed to check the "animated" box under my passive object and
2. I forgot to delete my cache after I checked the box.

Now it works as expected.

Comment: Hi Marc... you can click the tick next to your own answer to mark it as accepted, and others will know it's cleared up.

Comment: Thanks.. will do in.. 19 hours (that's what the system tells me when I click on it :)

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about the delay! Of course. Thanks for the info :)